# SQL: Sum two columns as 'Name' and use that name in where

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

MySQL:

I'm trying to Sum two columns in my database and return that results. I have that bit working.

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Money + Bank) AS TotalMoney FROM Players_Stats GROUP BY Id
```

Now I have the two columns totalling together i want to be able to use 'TotalMoney' in a where clause?

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Money + Bank) AS TotalMoney FROM Players_Stats
WHERE TotalMoney BETWEEN 100000 AND 1000000
GROUP BY Id
```

I'm getting a error saying TotalMoney does not exist but I have declared it.

Comment: take a look at this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/mysql-equivalent-of-with-in-oracle (spoiler: wrap your query in "proxy" select)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Money) + SUM(Bank) AS TotalMoney FROM Players_Stats 
GROUP BY Id HAVING SUM(Money) + SUM(Bank) BETWEEN 100000 AND 1000000
```

or:

```
SELECT ID,TotalMoney FROM 
(
SELECT Id, SUM(Money) + SUM(Bank) AS TotalMoney FROM Players_Stats 
    GROUP BY Id 
)Z WHERE Z.TotalMoney  BETWEEN 100000 AND 1000000
```

Try above query.

Comment: #1064 - YOU HAVE AN ERROR IN YOUR SQL SYNTAX; CHECK THE MANUAL THAT CORRESPONDS TO YOUR MYSQL SERVER VERSION FOR THE RIGHT SYNTAX TO USE NEAR 'WHERE SUM(MONEY) + SUM(BANK) BETWEEN 100000 AND 1000000' AT LINE 2

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `HAVING` clause.  It comes after the `GROUP BY`.  And it can use the table alias (in MySQL):

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Money + Bank) AS TotalMoney
FROM Players_Stats
GROUP BY Id
HAVING TotalMoney BETWEEN 100000 AND 1000000;
```